# ngOnInit not getting executed after constructor: Angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm trying to debug a problem where one of my component's constructor is getting executed but not ngOnInit, and hence the component doesn't load most of the content on the page. This is happening after my session token is renewed so it might be a bug in the logic how the renewal of the token is happening. But, is there a way to force the execution of ngOnInit()?
I tried using the following in my constructor:

```
applicationRef.tick()
```

and that works perfectly fine, i.e., ngOnInit is getting executed, but now I'm getting the following error in the console:

```
ERROR Error: ApplicationRef.tick is called recursively
```

Any suggestions for how I can resolve this?

Comment: You're doing something wrong. Please include the code that reproduces the issue

Comment: Please provide some code snippet to better understand the problem.

Comment: @yurzui, should I put code for renewing the adal token? Or the component that is having issues? Here is one issue that I'm suspecting is causing this issue: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/151

Comment: @Aiguo, make a private function, e.g. init() and call it in ngOnInit(){this.init()} and where you wish